# Lotus Designer software, and command and Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes

I recently tried this lotus script from internet, to add fields and get the input.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim celsius As String
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    x = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Field_F" )
    celsius = (x-32)*(5/9)
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Field_C", celcius) 
End Sub
```

When I execute I get type mis match error since the input i give is number and Variable celsius is declared as String.

Can any one tell what is wrong..
I know its something obvious but still i could'nt find since i m new to lotus notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not being consistent in your spelling of variables,

Dim celsius As String
Dim celsiusvalue As Double

celsius = Str$(celciusvalue)
Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Field_C", celcius)

Note spelling of celsius/celcius.

Use Option Declare in Options to avoid this, it'll catch the miss spellings as variable not declared.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing strings and numbers. Make sure the input for the calculation are numbers.

```
   Sub Click(Source As Button) 
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace 

    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument 
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument 

    Dim celsiusString As String 
    celsiusString = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Field_F" ) 

    Dim y As Double 
    y = Val(x) 

    Dim celsiusvalue As Double 
    celsiusvalue = (y-32)*(5/9) 

    celsiusString = Str$(celciusvalue) 
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Field_C", celsiusString) 
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get the error as "Incorrect argument type:string expected.
Below is the program and i gave number only as inputs.

Sub Click(Source As Button)
 Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
 Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
 Dim y As Double
 Dim celsius As String
 Dim celsiusvalue As Double
 Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
 x = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Field_F" )
 y = Val(x)
 celsiusvalue = (y-32)*(5/9)
 celsius = Str$(celciusvalue)
 Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Field_C", celcius) 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim celsius, x As Double
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    x = Cdbl(uidoc.FieldGetText( "Field_F" ))
    celsius = Cdbl((x-32)*(5/9))
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Field_C", Cstr(celcius)) 

End Sub
```